# Blazor: Is there a way to navigate to a in code dynamically instantiated component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Suppose this page/component:

```
// EditDetails.cs

@page "/details/{recordId}"

<p>Record Details - ID: @RecordId</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int RecordId {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way / did anybody implement a navigation engine so I could navigate to a in-code JIT instance of this component?

```
// ListRecords.cs

@page "/list"

(...markup...)

@code {
    EditDetails(int recordId)
    {
         var editComponent = new EditDetails() { RecordId = recordId };
         editComponent.NavigateTo(); // <== Something like this
    }
}
```

PS: I know I could conditionally render this component in markup, showing it only after a `recordId` is set and hiding the list. I'm just researching how far I can go with this supposed approach...

Comment: Well you can have a static method on the component that generates the URL based on your input and navigate to that... otherwise you have to add the component to the Render Tree (with methods from `ComponentBase`).

Comment: Blazor is a SPA, when you `navigate`, it is to a routable component, indicated by the `page` attribute. You don't create component instances and jump to them. You should research how Blazor works. Try blazor university.

Comment: @J.Hudler - Not me, I only do that for silly questions.  But [Politely] if you understand fundamentally how the Render process works you should realise that the answer to your question is a major hack job on the Renderer and the whole render process.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way / did anybody implement a navigation engine so I could navigate to a in-code JIT instance of this component?

No, I'm afraid not.  The instantation/destruct of components is handled by the Renderer.  The renderer interfaces with components through the `IComponent` interface.  A commentary on how the process works is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer!

Answer (score -1):

OK! It turns out it is possible.
So here it goes a naive implementation of a ViewStack engine.

Disclaimer:

- this may not be the original intent of the Blazor framework (I don't care);
- this may have some glitches;
- a unknown list of caveats may follow;

But it works! (Behold Blazor puritan police officers!)

---

1. First of all, a service to store the stacked views (that is, views that were "navigated" from other views) must be created. This service will also be responsible to navigate to such views:

   ```
   // ViewStackManager.cs
   public class ViewStackManager
   {
       private readonly Stack<ComponentBase> _viewStack = new();
       public ComponentBase? CurrentView { get => _viewStack.Any() ? _viewStack.Peek() : null; }    
       private NavigationManager _navManager;
       public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? CurrentViewChanged;

       public ViewStackManager(NavigationManager navManager)
       {
           _navManager = navManager;
           _navManager.LocationChanged += NavManager_LocationChanged;
       }

       private void NavManager_LocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           this.Clear();
       }

       public void PushView(ComponentBase view) => DoAndNotify(() => _viewStack.Push(view));
       public void PopView() => DoAndNotify(() => _viewStack.Pop());
       public void Clear() => DoAndNotify(() => _viewStack.Clear());    

       private void DoAndNotify(Action action)
       {
           action.Invoke();
           this.CurrentViewChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
       }
   }
   ```

2. Then we create a component that will render the topped view on the stack, if any. If the stack is empty, it should render the default view in route. During the render process, this component will use the stacked view as a template, copying its assigned `[Parameter]` properties inside the render tree.

   ```
   // ViewStack.cs
   public class ViewStack : IComponent
   {
       private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
       [Inject] ViewStackManager? _stackMgr { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

       public void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
       {
           _renderHandle = renderHandle;
           _stackMgr.CurrentViewChanged += CurrentViewChanged;
       }

       private void CurrentViewChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e) => RefreshCurrentView();    

       public Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
       {
           parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
           RefreshCurrentView();
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }

       private void RefreshCurrentView()
       {
           var currentView = _stackMgr?.CurrentView;
           if (currentView == null)
           {
               if (this.ChildContent != null)
                   _renderHandle.Render(this.ChildContent);
               return;
           }

           RenderFragment currentViewContent = builder =>
           {
               builder.OpenComponent(0, currentView.GetType());
               var counter = 0;
               // Set the view's parameters in the markup
               foreach (var paramProperty in currentView.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ParameterAttribute), false).Any()))
               {
                   builder.AddAttribute(counter++, paramProperty.Name, paramProperty.GetValue(currentView));
               }
               builder.CloseComponent(); // currentView
           };

           // Render the default layout, and the pushed component inside it
           // (TODO: retrieve the component specific layout, if exists)
           _renderHandle.Render(builder =>
           {
               builder.OpenComponent<LayoutView>(0);
               builder.AddAttribute(1, nameof(LayoutView.Layout), typeof(MainLayout));
               builder.AddAttribute(2, nameof(LayoutView.ChildContent), currentViewContent);
               builder.CloseComponent(); // LayoutView
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now we need to register the created `ViewStackManager` as a service, and put our ViewStack as the root component of our SPA:

   ```
   // Program.cs
   builder.Services.AddScoped<ViewStackManager>();

   // App.Razor
   <ViewStack>
       <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
           (...)
       </Router>
   </ViewStack>
   ```
4. Finally, we can use our stacking view engine to put a component on top of everything

   ```
   // ListRecords.razor
   <Markup />

   @code {
       [Inject] ViewStackManager? _stackMgr { get; set; }

       EditDetails(int recordId)
       {
            var editComponent = new EditDetails() { RecordId = recordId };
            _stackMgr.PushView(editComponent);
       }
   }
   ```
5. TODO: Called component must pop itself after its use. But you get the idea.